# (master) written in command line after the directory

Tags: git, heroku

I was installing **Heroku** in my device to deploy an application and wrote some commands using Hyper. After preparing the application, I added the content using Git. At that point, something called `(master)` appeared right at the end of the command line (after the current directory). I restarted Hyper, but it still showed up. What does `(master)` mean here, and does it affect anything?

See `(master)` written right at the end of each line

[image: See (master) written right at the end of each line]

(P.S. I am a newbie to web technologies and stuff)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+master+prompt

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Git, the `(master)` simply let's you know that you are on the [master branch](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell). The default branch name in Git is `master`.